# (Trackbars:8238): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:02:29.171: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, picamera

### Description

I'm designing an HSV color calibration menu on a **Raspberry-Pi** using **PiCamera**. Calibration using some of the features provided by OpenCV, namely the trackbar and masking.

### Source Code

Here is the source code that I use:

```
import numpy as np
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2 
 
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
raw_capture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))
 
time.sleep(0.1)

def nothing(x):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow("Trackbars")

cv2.createTrackbar("L - H", "Trackbars", 0, 179, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("L - S", "Trackbars", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("L - V", "Trackbars", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U - H", "Trackbars", 179, 179, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U - S", "Trackbars", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U - V", "Trackbars", 255, 255, nothing)

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(raw_capture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    l_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("L - H", "Trackbars")
    l_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("L - S", "Trackbars")
    l_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("L - V", "Trackbars")
    u_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("U - H", "Trackbars")
    u_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("U - S", "Trackbars")
    u_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("U - V", "Trackbars")

    lower_blue = np.array([l_h, l_s, l_v])
    upper_blue = np.array([u_h, u_s, u_v])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    number_of_white_pix = np.sum(mask == 255)

    cv2.putText(result,str(number_of_white_pix),(0,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("result", result)
     
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
     
    raw_capture.truncate(0)
     
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### Error or Warning

After I run the program, a warning like this always appears

```
(Trackbars:8238): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:02:29.171: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

### Question

1. What is the problem that causes this warning to appear?
2. How to handle it?

**Note:** I've googled it but what appears is not about trackbars, but NVIDIA GPU problems not a **Raspberry-Pi** problem.

Comment: It worked for me. I'm using OpenCV 4.5.5. But will not work OpenCV 4.6.0. I have to used picamera2. What is your OpenCV version?

Comment: @toyotaSupra hhmmmm, this program runs on my raspberry-pi but throws up an occasional warning. Im using openCV 3.2.0. Im using `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv`

Comment: OpenCV 3.2.0 is obsoleted. No you don't this install python3-opencv. The libcamera is newer version right now.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Should I use manual installation on github OpenCv?

Comment: No. It will not work for u. I testing OpenCV 4.6.0 and it better than 4.5.0